# Bootstrap 4 navbar height issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

So i decided to have a go with bootstrap 4 for this project, but the navbar is behaving rather weird. As you can see it widens it a whole lot, anyone know what the problem is? This problem is only present when i deploy the website. See code below (see navbar under code):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home/">@ViewBag.Title</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="btn navbar-btn" id="changeEmployeeBtn" href="/Home/ChangeEmployee/">Skift Medarbejder.</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-up">
        <br />
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn navbar-btn" href="" id="printBtn">Udskriv.</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-up">
        <hr />
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="navbar-text">Medarbejder: @HttpContext.Current.Request["EmployeeName"]</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: My Current Navbar]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i figured it out.

Apparently IIS doesnt like when you use minified versions of stuff, so switched to non-minified and its working perfectly now.